# Setting an app to launch after every reboot

Tags: android, native, launcher, setdefault

Ideally, we want our app to be the first one to get launched after every reboot, it is a system app so can we set it as default through code?

Answer (score 1):

best you can do is `BOOT_COMPLETED` handling

manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name="custom.package.BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Java side

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm afraid that with this approach you can never be sure if it will be called at first. And I know one "kind" of apps that will be called/opened earlier that any app will receive above broadast - devices Launcher

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not launch app immediately, takes more than 10 seconds to launch after reboot

Comment: yep, OS boot takes some time and your app isn't one and only starting at the beginning (besides other apps system has some "built-in" `Service`s and features, which are also starting taking precious computing time). so consider creating a Launcher or make some mods using root, best you can do